A question concerning facets of a polyhedron defined by a linear program
The below problem comes from the book of Bárány Combinatorial Convexity.
Suppose $X = \{b_1,\dots, b_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a set of $n>d+1$ points in general position and $a$ is a point chosen so that the number of (interiors of) simplices it is contained in is maximal. Without loss of generality assume that $X \cup \{a\}$ is in general position. Let $P$ be the convex polyhedron defined by the set of equations and equalities
$$
Mx = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad x\geq 0
$$
Where
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
b_1 & \cdots & b_n \\
1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We use the notation
$
\begin{bmatrix}
u \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$
to mean the $(d+1)\times 1$ matrix where the first $d$ entries are the entries of $u$ and the last entry is $1$. We further write $u \geq 0$ to mean that each entry of $u$ is at least zero. Define the support $I(x)$ of a $n$-dimensional vector as
$$
I(x) := \{i \in \{1,\dots, n\} \ : \ x_i \neq 0\}.
$$
I have been trying to prove the following

The inequality $x_1 \geq 0$ defines a facet of $P$ if and only if there exists an $x \in P$ such that $I(x) = \{2,3,\dots, n\}$.


Here is what I have tried so far:
First off we know that that $\dim(P) = n-d-1$. My argument for this is just that $\dim(\mathrm{null}(A)) = n-(d+1)$ by the rank-nullity theorem (This is lying a bit because we cannot just consider the solutions of the system $Mx = \binom{a}{1}$. We have to intersect the solution set with the region of the plane with all positive coordinates.)
For the direction $(\impliedby)$:
Define the hyperplane
$$
H_1 := \{u \in \mathbb{R}^n \ : \ \langle u, e_1 \rangle = 0 \}
$$
where $e_1$ is the first standard basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We would like to show that
$$
\dim(\mathrm{aff}(H_1 \cap P)) = n-d-2
$$
So we would like to find $n-d-2$ affinely independent vectors inside of $H_1 \cap P$. I have been trying to do this for small cases. For instance, consider the following scenario outlined by the picture below:

Here the corresponding polytope $P$ has dimension $5 - 2 - 1 = 2$. We have that there is an $x$ such that $I(x) = \{2,3,4,5\}$. Moreover, $a \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{conv}(\{b_2,b_3,b_4\}))$ and $a \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{conv}(\{b_2,b_3,b_5\}))$ (seen in colors green and blue respectively in the figure above). Both of these triangles correspond to vertices contained in the facet $H_1 \cap P$. However, I have been having a lot of trouble writing down carefully why these statements are true in general. I have been diving into Linear programming theory to see if there are some statements or proof techniques that will help me there. I have also tried an induction argument that uses Caratheodory's theorem but haven't been able to get this to work either.
Any advice on how to better and more effectively explore this problem and the polytope involved would be greatly appreciated.

It seems instead of "seen in colors blue and green respectively in the figure above" should be "seen in colors green and blue respectively in the figure above"

Ah good catch and also it should have said "$a \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{conv}(b_2,b_3,b_4))$ and $a \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{conv}(b_2,b_3,b_5))$" instead of "$a \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{conv}(x_2,x_3,x_4))$ and $a \in \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{conv}(x_2,x_3,x_5))$". I fixed both of these typos. Thank you for your careful reading.
